# Punctuation Problems

Tags: c#, string, concatenation

This is a program that reads in a CSV file, adds the values to a dictionary class and then analyses a string in a textbox to see if any of the words match the dictionary entry. It will replace abbreviations (LOL, ROFL etc) into their real words. It matches strings by splitting the inputted text into individual words.

```
public void btnanalyze_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var abbrev = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:/Users/Jordan Moffat/Desktop/coursework/textwords0.csv"))
    {
        string line;
        string[] row;

        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            row = line.Split(',');

            abbrev.Add(row[0], row[1]);
            Console.WriteLine(abbrev);
        }
    }

    string twitterinput;
    twitterinput = "";
    // string output;
    twitterinput = txtInput.Text;

    char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t' };
    string text = twitterinput;
    string[] words = twitterinput.Split(delimiterChars);

    string merge;
    foreach (string s in words)
    {
        if (abbrev.ContainsKey(s))
        {
            string value = abbrev[s];
            merge = string.Join(" ", value);
        }

        if (!abbrev.ContainsKey(s))
        {
            string not = s;
            merge = string.Join(" ", not);
        }

        MessageBox.Show(merge);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the program won't translate the word if there's punctuation. I realised the character set I was using meant that punctuation wasn't a problem, but also didn't allow me to retain it when printing out. Is there a way that I can ignore the last character, as opposed to removing it, and still retain it for the output? I was trying to write it into a new variable, but I can't find a way to do that either...

Comment: could you please add an example where you code fails

Comment: ok, so if I was to put in 
`LOL, hello`
it would just output 
`LOL, hello`
as opposed to 
`Laughing out loud, hello`

Comment: Ok I see your problem and if you have so many characters that delimited your input, you should change the focus of your problem using regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

That seems overly complicated.  You can do the same thing with regular expressions and backreferences.

```
foreach(var line in yourReader)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string,string>(); // your replacement dictionaries
    foreach(var kvp in dict)
    {
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(line,"(\s|,|\.|:|\\t)" + kvp.Key + "(\s|,|\.|:|\\t)","\0" + kvp.Value + "\1");
    }
}
```

I hacked this regex together so it may not be right, but it's the basic idea.